# Combo box y carga de horas

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, combobox

Bueno les comento un poco, estoy haciendo un sistema para agregar turnos, lo que estoy tratado de resolver ahora es mostrar "los Horarios disponibles" que tendría el Medico que queda comprometido con el turno.
En la base de datos tengo un stock procedure que recibe los parámetros para inserción del Turno, entre ellas las fecha, la cual la trato como un char(14) asi : "20210524 19:05"

Primero cree una consulta que devuelva las horas OCUPADAS por el Medico :

```
SELECT T.idTurno, convert(char(5),fechaturno, 108) Horas_Ocupadas from Turno T INNER JOIN TurnoPaciente TP ON T.idTurno = TP.idTurno Where TP.idMedico = @idMedico
```

Esta consulta me devuelve un idTurno y Horas_Ocupadas asi : "45 19:30"

Estoy tratando de comprender porque NO CARGA este combobox dependiente con la consulta anterior.
Aqui les dejo el codigo.
El IdMedico para la variable de la consulta lo obtengo de otro combobox.

```
    public void cargar_horas(string idMedico)
    {
     String consulta = "SELECT T.idTurno, convert(char(5),fechaturno, 108) Horas_Ocupadas from 
                        Turno T INNER JOIN TurnoPaciente TP 
                        ON T.idTurno = TP.idTurno 
                        Where TP.idMedico = @idMedico";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(consulta, Conexion.ConectaDB());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("idMedico", idMedico);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    DataRow fila = dt.NewRow();
    fila["Horas_Ocupadas"] = "Seleccione una hora";
    dt.Rows.InsertAt(fila, 1);
        
    cboxhoras.ValueMember = "T.idTurno";
    cboxhoras.DisplayMember = "Horas_Ocupadas";
    cboxhoras.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

Un saludo y gracias

Comment: ya probaste quitando el alias (T.) al value member, quedaría así : cboxhoras.ValueMember = "idTurno"

Comment: Hola en esta parte cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("idMedico", idMedico);
No le pusiste el @ a la variable @idMedico
Si lo que comentas del combo puedes probar con esto ya que recibes el sender
ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)sender;
            int selectedIndex = cmb.SelectedIndex;
          var dato = cmb.SelectedValue.ToString();

Answer (score 0):

Respondo.
Probé cargar directamente le método : cargar_horas() y asignarle un valor a la variable y funciona correctamente.
Lo que creo que pasa es que el combobox del cual el método recibe la variable no la esta enviando, pero no estoy seguro del porque. Agrego el código del combobox

```
private void horas_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cboxmedicos.SelectedValue.ToString() != null )
            {
                string idMedico = cboxmedicos.SelectedValue.ToString();
                cargar_horas(idMedico);
            }
```

Comment: Las respuestas se utilizan para responder a las preguntas. Puedes editar tu pregunta tantas veces como sea necesario. Si quieres mejorar tu pregunta, puedes coger el texto que has puesto aquí, incluirlo en tu pregunta, y luego eliminar esta respuesta.